# Creating two views on runtime and placing one right of first one

Tags: android, android-view

So I'm creating ImageView and TextView in the runtime and I want the TextView to be placed right of the ImageView.

I'm trying this simple code:

```
private void loadContent(Module module) {
    this.removeAllViewsInLayout();      
    this.addView(getModuleIconView(module));
    this.addView(getModuleNameView(module));
}

private ImageView getModuleIconView(Module module) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(context);
    view.setImageResource(module.getIconResId());   
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(120, 120);                
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setId(1); //seting some id for the view
    return view;
}

private TextView getModuleNameView(Module module) {
    TextView view = new TextView(context);
    view.setText(module.getName()); 
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1); //hoping for view to be placed right of the ImageView which id was set to 1
    return view;
}
```

What Do I do wrong here? The TextView is placed on my ImageView ignoring the RIGHT_OF

Need to mention the class inherits from RelativeLayout

Comment: this.addView, what's this ("this" the object)?

Comment: why don't you try view.addView instead of this.addview ??

Comment: this.addView is view.addView actually. The class inherits from RelativeLayout

Comment: How does that answer the question? RelativeLayout I'm using is empty, and I want to fill it on Runtime. There are no xml designed elements to place something between them... besides it's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my stupid mistake. Third method leaks setLayoutParams

So correct method body is:

```
private TextView getModuleNameView(Module module) {
    TextView view = new TextView(context);
    view.setText(module.getName()); 
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    return view;
}
```